# cytoscape.js select all nodes in an (externally supplied) array

Tags: cytoscape.js

This works nicely:

cy.filter("node[name='KRAS']").select()

How would I do the following?  (in pseudo-code, where %in% [if it existed] would test for set membership):

cy.filter("node[name %in% ['KRAS', 'TP53', 'PDGFRA']]).select()

Thanks!

- Paul

Comment: I sometimes have 100 nodes I want to select, based on calculations in R.  If I loop through that many nodes, calling filter & select on each, it takes about 8 seconds.  I hope that making a single call to filter and select, against an array of node names, will be much faster.

Answer (score 7):

As you suspect, it's better to batch calls that result in rendering (like `eles.select()`) -- it batches stylesheet applications and notifications to the renderer to make things faster.

As for your selector, remember that concatenating selectors together is a logical AND and that separating selectors with a comma is a logical OR.  So, your result is:

```
cy.filter('node[foo = "bar"], node[foo = "baz"], node[foo = "bat"]').select();
```

If the graph is static or changes infrequently, you can also do some caching.  By factoring out common parts of each selector, the overall filtering becomes cheaper -- i.e. in your case, if they're all nodes, just filter the set of nodes for each specific selector:

```
var nodes = cy.filter('node'); // a cached copy of nodes

// each time you want to filter
nodes.filter('[foo = "bar], [foo = "baz"], [foo = "bat"]').select();
```

Notice how the second `filter()` call will be faster in this case because it's only operating on a subset of the graph.